# Дихотомия. Бин поиск

Tags: c++, массивы, двоичный-поиск

Имеется массив 1 и 0, размером `N`.

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Нужно за `logN` определить место на котором стоит самая правая(последняя единица). Если единиц нет вовсе вывести `-1`.

В голову пришел бинарный поиск:
- если попали на ноль, идем влево
- если единица пробуем расширится пройдясь правее

Но с написанием кода возникли проблемы (((

Comment: Имеется стандартный алгоритм std::lower_bound, который вы можете использовать для поиска 0 или std::upper_bound который можете использовать для поиска 1

Comment: Массив именно такой - сначала единицы, потом нули?

Comment: Ну сами же пишете - дихотомия. Две переменные: начало, конец, выбираем середину, проверяем, сужаем диапазон. Повторить, пока диапазон больше единицы.

Comment: Да массив, именно такой!

Comment: А как сужать диапазон и какое условие выхода?

Comment: условие выхода написано. сужать диапазон: `if(arr[middle] == 1){start=middle;}else {end=middle;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться либо стандартным алгоритмом `std::upper_bound` с использованием 1 в качестве аргумента, или алгоритмом `std::lower_bound`  с использованием 0 в качестве аргумента.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };

    auto it = std::upper_bound(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
        1, std::greater<int>());

    if (it != std::begin(a))
    {
        std::cout << "The last 1 is at the position "
            << std::distance(std::begin(a), std::prev(it))
            << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "There is no 1 in the array" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
The last 1 is at the position 4
```

Вместо выражения

```
std::distance(std::begin(a), std::prev(it))
```

вы можете использовать выражение

```
std::distance(std::begin(a), it) - 1
```

И тогда вы получите искомую позицию, если 1 присутствует в массиве или -1, если нет ни одной 1.

Comment: std алгоритмы гарантировано O(log N)?

Comment: @DNS Да, используется двоичный поиск.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо псевдокода приведу javascript

```js
function search(arr) {
  // стартовый диапазон
  let start = 0, end = arr.length;
  do {
    // середина
    let middle = Math.floor((end-start)/2)+start;

    if (arr[middle] == 1) {
      start = middle; // обрезаем половину со старта
    } else {
      end = middle;   // обрезаем половину с хвоста
    }
  } while(end - start > 1); // остался один элемент
  return arr[start] == 1 ? start : -1; // нашли?
}

console.log(search([1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])); // 2
console.log(search([1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])); // 4
console.log(search([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])); // 0
console.log(search([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])); // -1
```